# Php pdo with SQL Server not run trigger after update

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, triggers

I'm using PHP 5.4.10, Windows Server with IIS and connecting to remote SQL Server 2008 (v10.0.4). Using Microsoft DLL for connection to SQL Server.

Everything works fine, only one important thing don't work. I have one table, where on update  trigger is defined. When I make update, everything looks OK, but trigger don't run and update isn't executed.

When I made the same order via SQL editor, everything work fine and trigger is executed.

Query is:

```
update db.user_obj_hlv 
set i_action = '1' 
where doklad='201339'
```

Comment: What does the trigger do? Can we see the definition of it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's remote IS and I'dont have access to it. The trigger should found a new order in IS. I don't understand what is different betwen call command from PHP PDO and from SQL manager. IN php i use `PDO->query("update db.user_obj_hlv set i_action ='1' where doklad='201339'")` and it return true as result, but nothing is executed....